# overloading/implicit operator for 'as'

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

```
class Person
{
   string Name;
   int Age;
}
```

I want to be able to cast a string to Person implicitly like following

```
var mrFoo = "Foo" as Person;
```

I know I can do the following by defining implicit casting

```
Person mrFoo = "Foo";
```

But I'm specific to use "as" operator

Comment: You can define explicit cast operator overloads and use an explicit cast `(Person)` instead of `as` operator.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The "as" operator *never* uses user-defined conversions - only reference conversions and unboxing conversions. Basically, the reference in question already has to be the right type.

Personally I would *strongly* advise you to stay away from conversion operators (especially implicit ones) for the vast majority of cases. Usually having a conversion *method* is clearer, e.g. `Person.FromString(...)`.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using a parameterized constructor?

var mrFoo = new Person("Foo");

Comment: This is the most sensible way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use the `as` operator, since you can do this with the `implicit` operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.71).aspx

Something along these lines should work:

```
public static implicit operator Person(string s)
{
  Person p = new Person() {Name = s};
  return p;
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```
Person p = "John Doe";
```

Comment: So, how exactly are you able to overload an operator in a sealed system type? Pretty sure you can't do this.