# object to struct with as operator

Tags: c#

Why does the first one work but not the second one? Is there anything to worry about, when converting objects to structs?

```
struct Hex { /* ... */ }
object actionData = GetData();
```

**1:**

```
bool isHex = actionData is Hex;
Hex hexx = (Hex)actionData;
```

**2:**

```
Hex hex = actionData as Hex;
```

Comment: I think this may be what you are after - [overloading/implicit operator for 'as'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204104/overloading-implicit-operator-for-as)

Comment: **3:** `if (actionData is Hex hexx) {...}` - matching by example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) returns `null` if type check fails:

> The expression of the form `E as T`
> where `E` is an expression that returns a value and `T` is the name of a type or a type parameter, produces the same result as: `E is T ? (T)(E) : (T)null` except that `E` is only evaluated once.

Which can't be done if `T` is non-nullable value type (so compiler emits the error). Using nullable value type as `T` will work:

```
object actionData = new Hex(); // your code returning boxed Hex
Hex? hex = actionData as Hex?;
if(hex.HasValue)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**

Assuming that the result of `GetData()` is of correct the correct type (ie something that is castable to the `Hex` struct the following will successfully compile and also work at runtime

```
struct Hex { ...} 
...
Hex foo = (Hex)GetData();
```

because you can always write an explicit cast (ie you are telling the compiler you know what you are doing and it shouldn't care about possible incompatibilities)

**Case 2**

If the result of `GetData()` is something, that *isn't*  castable to `Hex`
the same code

```
struct Hex { ...} 
...
Hex foo = (Hex)GetData();
```

will still successfully compile (because you are overruling the compiler). But it will throw an `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

**Case 3**

Your second snippet won't even compile. Because the result of the `as` operator is nullable (ie `as` returns `null` if the typecheck fails) and you cannot assign `null` to a non-nullable struct.

```
struct Hex { ...} 
...
Hex hex = actionData as Hex;
```

If you want to be able to compile this, you have to make the variable nullable like

```
Hex? hex = actionData as Hex?;
if (hex.HasValue) {
  ... //conversion succeeded
} else {
  ... //conversion failed and hex is null
}
```

or you make `Hex` a `class` instead of a `struct`. Because a `class` is a [*reference type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) which can also be `null`, but a `struct` is a [*value type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) which cannot be null.